# Differential Cryptanalysis

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, differential-analysis, lightweight

How do I find the differential characteristics using techniques Shrinking ?

How do I extract the key on Differential Cryptanalysis using the technique Shrinking in Blockcipher Algorithm?

Shrinking technique is a technique that was made by Eli Biham for cryptanalysis Skipjack 1998.